# Como fazer uma MLP no R cuja saída seja a posteriori e o conjunto de teste classificado?

Tags: r, mlp

Usei a função "neuralnet" do pacote de mesmo nome, mas não consegui rodar. Sim, desejo classificar, logo tenho rótulos.

Comment: Deu algum erro quando você tentou rodar?

Comment: Oi Wagner, você poderia detalhar mais a sua pergunta? As seguintes informações são bastantes úteis: Quais são seus dados? Qual é o código que você tentou rodar? Qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: Wagner, seria interessante você trazer o exemplo específico do problema e explicar melhor o erro que você está tendo.

Comment: Prezados meu problema estava em rodas a  função "confusionMatrix", pois tinha três rótulos e ela não dava uma matriz 3x3 e sim uma 3x2. Mas consegui consertar, o problema era que o conjunto de treinamento era maior que o de teste. Muito grato!